# Mounting a timing pulley on a ball screw shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, pulleys

I have a pretty basic question.

I need to install a timing pulley on a ball screw shaft (6mm):
http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/2816419/

The processed end (the pointy side) of the shaft is secured by a support mount, I need to place a timing pulley on the other side. I'm not sure how to go about this. E.g. this pulley: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/timing-belt-pulleys/0744508/

Would a mounting hub or a pulley with a holding screw work? Thanks.

Comment: A professor once told me that a set screw is used to secure a pulley just long enough to drill a hole and insert a pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to find one that has a configurable machined length for the support end. This way, you will have the screw flats on the fixed end and a machined "stepped" end on the support side for the pulley to attach to, just after the supporter. Just make sure the stepped end on the support side is long enough to contain BOTH the pulley and the support mount.

[image]

Comment: How would you go about mounting the timing pulley in the middle part of the screw?

Answer (score 0):

For such a configuration the screw will need to be fixed at one or both ends so it cannot turn but move freely back and forth; unless you want the timing pulley and ACME nut to traverse back and forth then the screw must not rotate or move freely on its axis.